# What is 'linux-libc-dev'? "Linux kernel headers for development" for another kernel series in software updater

Tags: kernel, updates, linux-headers

Some updates has recently become available. Below is the screen-shot:

[image]

As you guys can see, under the **Security Updates**, one of the updates of **Ubuntu base** is **Linux kernel headers for development**...

The description of this update shows the following:

[image]

It says that I have headers for Kernel 4.4.0-93.116! I don't get it, but I'm not using the 4.4.x LTS kernel, rather I'm using the following:

```
uname -r
4.10.0-28-generic
```

So how come I have headers for another kernel series installed? And now there's a new version to get updated!

I'm always trying to stick to the kernel I have...(even though I'm a little bit worried that I'm not using any LTS kernel like 4.4.x series, which I did on Mint), but now this seems very confusing!!

What should I do now? Any explanation why do I have headers for another kernel series installed on my system?!

Comment: These are not kernel headers. Everything is OK. You should have `linux-headers` for the 4.10 kernel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `linux-libc-dev` package contains headers of user-space libraries.

In Ubuntu LTS releases they are not upgraded with the HWE kernels.

It is normal, and you don't need to change it.

The Linux headers are in another package called `linux-headers...` that does match the kernel version.

See `apt-cache show linux-libc-dev`

```
Linux Kernel Headers for development
 This package provides headers from the Linux kernel.  These headers
 are used by the installed headers for GNU glibc and other system
 libraries. They are NOT meant to be used to build third-party modules for
 your kernel. Use linux-headers-* packages for that.
```

Almost exactly what I wrote before ;-)

Comment: So I don't need to update "Linux kernel headers for development" right?@Pilot6

Comment: It is getting updates. So let the system work as intended. Just install what is suggested.